# Laravel - return data ajax to Charts view

Tags: ajax, laravel, charts

I am working with a laravel application, my problem is that I want to output the Chartjs view with ajax using ConsoleTv/Charts.
This is my code:
**Route:**

```
Route::get('month/{month}','AjaxController@getMonth')->middleware('ajax');
```

**Controller**

```
public function getMonth($month){

        if ($request->ajax()) {

            $sql = Ticket::select('name')
                ->selectRaw('count(id) as status1')
                ->whereMonth('Date','=',$month)->get();

            $labels = $sql->pluck('name');
            $values = $sql->pluck('status1');

            $month = new Charts();
            $month->title('Title');
            $month->labels($labels);
            $month->dataset('Tiket', 'bar',$values);

            return json_encode(compact('month'));

        }
```

**Ajax:**

```
$('.secCharts').on('change', function (e) {
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = this.value; 
        var month= 4;
        if(valueSelected == 1){
        $.get('month/'+month,function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#bar-charts').html(data);
            }); 
        }
    });
```

My problem is how to push the data variable into view:

```
<div id="bar-charts" class="box-content">
    {!! $month->container() !!}
</div>
{!! $month->script() !!}
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [example](https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/bqaGRR)

This field is wrong in your code
You must call the function

```
            $('#bar-charts').html(data);
```

You have enough

this part used

```
var getData = function() {  $.ajax({
url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + postId + '/comments',
success: function(data) {
  // process your data to pull out what you plan to use to update the chart
  // e.g. new label and a new data point

  // add new label and data point to chart's underlying data structures
  myChart.data.labels.push("Post " + postId++);
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(getRandomIntInclusive(1, 25));

  // re-render the chart
  myChart.update();
}
```

});
};

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it didn't work because I came from laravel chart ConsoleTV